# how can we use Coalesce in python for multiple data frames using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

How can we use Coalesce with multiple data frames.

`columns_List = Emp_Id, Emp_Name, Dept_Id...`

I have two data frames getting used in python script. `df1[Columns_List]` , `df2[columns_List]`. In both the dataframes  i have same columns used but i will be having different values in both dataframes.

How can i use Coalesce so that lets say :In Dataframe `df1[Columns_List]` -- I have `Emp_Name null` then i want to pick `Emp_Name` from `df2[Columns_list]`.

I am trying to create an output CSV file.

Please sorry if my framing of question is wrong..

Please find below sample data.

For Dataframe1 -- df1[Columns_List] .. Please find below output

```
EmpID,Emp_Name,Dept_id,DeptName
1,,1,
2,,2,
```

For Dataframe2 -- df2[Columns_List] .. Please find below output

```
EmpID,Emp_Name,Dept_id,DeptName
1,XXXXX,1,Sciece
2,YYYYY,2,Maths
```

I have source as Json file. Once i parse the data by python , i am using 2 dataframes in the same script. In Data frame 1 ( df1) i have Emp_Name & Dept_Name as null. In that case i want to pick data from Dataframe2 (df2).

In the above example i have provided few columns. But i may have n number of columns. but column ordering and column names will be always same. I am trying to achieve in such a way if any of the column from df1 is null then i want to pick value from df2.

Is that possible.. Please help me with any suggestionn...

Comment: @sammywemmy -- I have added some sample output data. Please let me know if i need to add any more details

Comment: Do you want to replace values which are Null or which are empty? By null I mean numpy.NaN, by empty could be an empty string.

Comment: @Valentino .. Thanks a lot for the reply. Please consider it as empty..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html). This method does what you need: it builds a dataframe taking elements from two dataframes according to a custom function.
You can then write a custom function which picks the element from dataframe one unless that is null, in which case the element is taken from dataframe two.

Consider the two following dataframe. I built them according to your examples but with a small difference to emphatize that only emtpy string will be replaced:

```
columnlist = ["EmpID", "Emp_Name", "Dept_id", "DeptName"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, None, 1, np.NaN], [2, np.NaN, 2, None]], columns=columnlist)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, "XXX", 2, "Science"], [2, "YYY", 3, "Math"]], columns=columnlist)
```

They are:

```
df1
   EmpID  Emp_Name  Dept_id  DeptName
0      1       NaN        1       NaN
1      2       NaN        2       NaN

df2
   EmpID Emp_Name  Dept_id DeptName
0      1      XXX        1  Science
1      2      YYY        3     Math
```

What you need to do is:

```
ddf = df1.combine(df2, lambda ss, rep_ss : pd.Series([r if pd.isna(x) else x for x, r in zip(ss, rep_ss)]))
```

to get `ddf`:

```
ddf
   EmpID Emp_Name  Dept_id DeptName
0      1      XXX        1  Science
1      2      YYY        2     Math
```

As you can see, only Null values in `df1` have been replaced with the corresponding values in `df2`.

#### EDIT: A bit deeper explanation

Since I've been asked in the comments, let me give a bit of explanation more on the solution:

```
ddf = df1.combine(df2, lambda ss, rep_ss : pd.Series([r if pd.isna(x) else x for x, r in zip(ss, rep_ss)]))
```

Is a bit compact, but there is nothing much than some basic python techiques like list comprehensions, plus the use of `pandas.DataFrame.combine`. The pandas method is detailed in the docs I linked above. It compares the two dataframes column by column: the columns are passed to a custom function which must return a `pandas.Series`. This Series become a column in the returned dataframe.
In this case, the custom function is a `lambda`, which uses a list comprehension to loop over the pairs of elements (one from each column) and pick only one element of the pair (the first if not null, otherwise the second).

Comment: I have tried below one. But Empty values remains same..


df3 = df2.combine(df1, lambda ss, rep_ss : pd.Series([r if x == "" else x for x, r in zip(ss, rep_ss)]))

Comment: It does not work bidirectionally. It must be: `df_with_empty_strings.combine(df_filler, lambda ...)`.

Comment: @If i want to replace EMpty values in df2 with df1. Can you help me with that complete syntax please..

Comment: In your question is `df1` which haves empty values. If it's the opposite, just switch `df1` and `df2`. Otherwise I don't understand anymore what you want to do.

Comment: Yes , i have used the same. sorry for confusion. Values are still remains empty...

Comment: As per you logic mentioned i have used in the same way, but values are not getting replaced. It still remains blank

Comment: The string you want to replace, are they empty? Or filled with spaces?

Comment: @when i create both the dataframes into different csv files, it shows as empty "" . But when i print dataframes while executing in python it shows " None "  for some columns , " NaN " for some columns

Comment: Ah, so they are not empty strings. Ok, let me fix my answer

Comment: @Arya answer fixed

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was fixed now. I want to give "n" number of votes..  Can you help me to understand the sentence. how it works

df2.combine(df1, lambda ss, rep_ss : pd.Series([r if pd.isna(x) else x for x, r in zip(ss, rep_ss)]))

Comment: @Arya I've edited the answer to give a bit more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mask to get null values and replace those.  The best part is that you don't have to eyeball anything; the function will find what to replace for you.

You can also adjust the pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes() function to suit your needs, or just go through multiple dtypes with appropriate conversion and detection measures being used.

```
import pandas as pd

ddict1 = {
    'EmpID':[1,2],
    'Emp_Name':['',''],
    'Dept_id':[1,2],
    'DeptName':['',''],
}

ddict2 = {
    'EmpID':[1,2],
    'Emp_Name':['XXXXX','YYYYY'],
    'Dept_id':[1,2],
    'DeptName':['Sciece','Maths'],
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(ddict1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(ddict2)


def replace_df_values(df_A, df_B):
    ## Select object dtypes
    for i in df_A.select_dtypes(include=['object']):
        ### Check to see if column contains missing value
        if len(df_A[df_A[i].str.contains('')]) > 0:
            ### Create mask for zero-length values (or null, your choice)
            mask = df_A[i] == ''
            ### Replace on 1-for-1 basis using .loc[]
            df_A.loc[mask, i] = df_B.loc[mask, i]

### Pass dataframes in reverse order to cover both scenarios
replace_df_values(df1, df2)
replace_df_values(df2, df1)
```

Initial values for df1:

```
   EmpID Emp_Name  Dept_id DeptName
0      1                 1         
1      2                 2
```

Output for df1 after running function:

```
   EmpID Emp_Name  Dept_id DeptName
0      1    XXXXX        1   Sciece
1      2    YYYYY        2    Maths
```

Comment: If df2 is having empty , then i can replace with df1

Comment: Hi.  I updated and made the arguments generic.  Then, you can run it with df2 being the first argument and df1 being the second.

Comment: @ i am getting  " ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values " is this like Empty string is getting considered as NA/NAN. ??

Comment: I have modified one line : " if len(df_A[df_A[i].str.contains('', na=False)]) > 0: "... But in the final output after replace_df_values i am getting only one value  as "None" , i am not getting expected output..

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your dataframes:

```
# df1
    EmpID   Emp_Name    Dept_id DeptName
0   1       1   
1   2       2   

# df2
    EmpID   Emp_Name    Dept_id DeptName
0   1   XXXXX   1   Sciece
1   2   YYYYY   2   Maths
```

1. If you want to replace missing values (NaN) from df1.column with existing values from df2.column, you could use `.fillna()`. For example:

```
df1['Emp_Name'].fillna(df2['Emp_Name'], inplace=True)
```

---

```
# df1

    EmpID   Emp_Name    Dept_id DeptName
0   1   XXXXX   1   
1   2   YYYYY   2
```

2. If you want to replace all values from a given column with the values from the same column of another dataframe, you could use list comprehension.

```
df1['DeptName'] = [ each for each in list(df2['DeptName'])]
```

---

```
    EmpID   Emp_Name    Dept_id DeptName
0   1   XXXXX   1   Sciece
1   2   YYYYY   2   Maths
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Without mentioning the column name can i make it as generic as because i have n number of columns..